# PHP Construct not working?

Tags: php, oop, class, constructor

I have the following code:

```
<?php

class Human()
{

    function __construct()
    {
        echo "A human was born";
    }

}

$Person1 = new Human();

?>
```

I'm trying to get it to print out "A human was born", but it's just not having it!

Comment: Turn on error reporting, you should be getting a parse error

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Remove the `()` after `class Human`.

```
<?php

class Human
{

    function __construct()
    {
        echo "A human was born";
    }

}

$Person1 = new Human();

?>
```

Comment: 15k answering too localized for +7 - typical :)

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your syntax, you should declare the class as:

```
class Human {

    function __construct()
    {
        echo "A human was born";
    }

}
```

Without the `()` after the name of the class.